# Can OpenLayers3 reproject vector tile (MVT) layers?

Tags: openlayers-3, vector-tiles

I'm trying to use OpenLayers to display vector tile layers and basemaps that I've created and am serving.

The raster basemaps I'm using are in EPSG:4326, and I'd like to overlay the MVT layers, reprojected into EPSG:4326 as well.

However, it's not seeming to work. When I have a map with the view projection set to EPSG:3857, everything looks fine. The basemap, which is in EPSG:4326, is reprojected to EPSG:3857 and the vector layer looks exactly right.

But when I change the map view projection to EPSG:4326, the raster basemap looks okay, but the MVT layer will not display. No tile requests are made, and I get no JS errors.

I have the `projection` attribute of my MVT source set to `EPSG:3857`. I've tried defining my own TileGrid as well as `ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()`, but nothing works when the main map view projection is set to EPSG:4326.

I know MVT support in OpenLayers is fairly new, perhaps this isn't something supported yet?

I'm trying to do this because my vector data was originally in EPSG:4326. I have to convert it to EPSG:3857 in order to serve it as MVT tiles, but I'd like to be able to show it in its original projection.

Comment: It is possible to generate tiles for 4326, but that does require some hackary. Not sure exactly how they did it. https://cloud.maptiler.com/maps/basic-4326/